# Could my forms be hacked

Tags: javascript, php

I posted a question yesterday, which I intend to get back to today however I wrote some JavaScript as a first line of prevention against XSS. However when testing this on my live server I catch some invalid input as the javascript catches the php section. My form uses post and php isn't in my form items (i haven't typed it in). Could this be picking up the form action or something? I'm baffeled, Any ideas

Here is my code, it is triggered on the submit button.

```
    function validateForBadNess(){

var theShit = new Array("*","^", "$", "(",")","{", "}","[", "]","\\", "|", "'","/","?",",","=",">","gt","lt", "<","script","`","´","php");
var tagName = new Array();

tagName[0] = "input";
tagName[1] = "select";
tagName[2] = "textbox";
tagName[3] = "textarea";

for (ms=0;ms<tagName.length;ms++){

 // loop through  the elements of the form
 var formItems = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName[ms]);

  for (var xs=0;xs<formItems.length;xs++){

   var thisString = formItems[xs].value;

   // loop through bad array
   for (zs in theShit){

    //alert(thisString + " " + thisString.indexOf(theShit[zs]))
    if(thisString.indexOf(theShit[zs]) >= 0){

    alert("Sorry but the following character: " + theShit[zs] + " is not permitted. Please omit it from your input.\nIf this is part of your password please contact us to heave your password reset.")
    return false;

    }

     }



  // loop for formitems 
  }

 // tagName toop
 }
// original condition
}
```

Comment: Others have pointed you in the right direction, but I just wanted to mention that if you WERE going to do something like this, the way you're doing it is pretty messy and unnecessary. Most of your code could be replaced with a relatively simple regular expression, no need for complicated setups of arrays etc.

Comment: "Sorry but the following character: " + theShit[zs] + " is not permitted. Please try hacking with another one, say 'KEVIN MITNICK' out loud if you want to receive some suggestions." xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you do is totally unnecessary and useless in terms of protection against attacks. Any JavaScript based "protection" will be circumvented within seconds, and legitimate users will not be happy to be unable to use the `$` sign for example. Always assume that any incoming data *can* have been tampered with.

You need to be careful when *outputting* data on the server side. Use `htmlspecialchars()` on any incoming textual data. If you have incoming HTML you need "cleaned", use HTML purifier as suggested by Sarfraz.

Related SO reading:

- [What are the best practices for avoid xss attacks in a PHP site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoid-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site)
- [XSS filtering function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336776/xss-filtering-function-in-php)

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use famous **[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)** instead?

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant
>   HTML filter library written in    PHP.
>   HTML Purifier will not only remove all
>   malicious    code (better known as
>   XSS) with a thoroughly audited,
>   secure yet permissive whitelist,   it
>   will also make sure your documents are
>   standards compliant, something only
>   achievable with a    comprehensive
>   knowledge of W3C's specifications.
>   Tired of using BBCode due to the
>   current landscape of deficient or
>   insecure HTML filters? Have a
>   WYSIWYG editor but never been able to
>   use it? Looking    for high-quality,
>   standards-compliant, open-source
>   components for that    application
>   you're building? HTML Purifier is for
>   you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to do your input validation on the server. An attacker can just send request, while completely bypassing a browser and your javascript. To be securely filter the input you have to do it on the server side.

A good way to do that is to use php's [filter extension](http://php.net/filter).

If you want to only display input again use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Answer (score 0):

[Try replacing the text to HTML entities :) that way you won't have to worry about this ;)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: Hi there, I do use HTML entities htmlentities($str) on my input. My site is still getting hacked so I thought some JS may help