# Sanitizing Form Input for administrators

Tags: php, sanitization

In my site's administration area, I have been using mysqli_real_escape_string when retrieving form input that goes into the database. It works fine but I realize that it does not prevent script injections. I mean I can pass through scripts like:

```
<script>alert('hello');</script>
```

What do I use in addition to this to prevent a malicious admin from injecting some nasty stuff?

- `htmlentities()`?
- `strip_tags()`?
- `htmlspecialchars()`?

What is the proper way to sanitize form input in back-end forms where html is not required for input data? I am confused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`htmlentities()` and `htmlspecialchars()` are used when you're outputting data. Encoding and escaping are different.

If you don't want HTML, my recommendation would be to use `strip_tags()` to clean it of any HTML tags and use `html*` when you're outputting the content.

Also, you might consider switching to [MySQL PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php). This is a much more preferred and secure way of running your queries.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `htmlentities()` .

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is `Cross Site Scripting` or `XSS` for short. Searching for that should give you plenty of resources, such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336776/xss-filtering-function-in-php) right here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The proper answer is highly dependent on your application.

Many administration systems *need* a way for admins to manipulate HTML.  But some HTML is more dangerous than others.

As JohnP said, [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/strip_tags) can be handy, since the second parameter allows you to explicitly allow certain, harmless tags (like  or ), while stripping out anything else (like  or )

If you need more sophistication than that, you'll need to do a more careful analysis and come up with a solution tailored to your needs.  (Hint: If that solution involves using regular expressions to match HTML tags, you probably want to take a step back)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `magic_quotes` function to sanitize if you're using php 4 or less php 5.2 or less.

Comment: @user493350 You _could_ do that but I would strongly recommend against it, as does the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). It has a whole load of security issues.