# PHP/JS: how to clean user input/output

Tags: php, security, xss, user-input

For example, let's say I have a website that receives and displays user comments (text). I am concerned with vulnerabilities from receiving user submissions and also when the submissions are displayed.

Concerns:

- Cross-site scripting attack
- SQL injection

My question is are there more attacks that could come from user text inputs? Also, in what ways can I guard against such attacks using PHP, Javascript?

Thanks, and merry Xmas!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [XSS filtering function in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336776/xss-filtering-function-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is not a barrier from XSS, CSRF attacks, so you should care about server side protection. If you talk about functions then these will help you from XSS: htmlentities(), strip_tags(), utf8_decode(); and as Zar said mysql_real_escape_string will help you from SQL injection.
There are a lot of articles devoted to SQL injections, XSS, CSRF, sessions hijacking. Go to http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/ and read it all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strip_tags($var)` to guard yourself against XSS.

`mysql_real_escape_string($var)` will give you basic SQL injection protection.

Comment: Of course, it's preferable to use prepared statements and PDO instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: strip_tags() is a really shitty function for preventing xss,  and paramaterized queries is the best way to stop sqli.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at php [Filter Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php), which made to clean and validate different types of data, from boolean to email addresses, functions like [filter_input](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) and [filter_input_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php) could make your application more secure and smart.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using ajax to send some form data to the server as part of url, encode them like this

```
encodeURIComponent(yourFormInputData);
```

and remember to decode them on the server side.

Comment: That fails to solve either the issue of XSS or SQL injection.