# PHP File upload security - keeping the original file name

Tags: php, security, file-upload, filenames

I want to allow registered users of a website (**PHP**) to upload files (documents), which are going to be publicly available for download.
In this context, is the fact that I keep the file's original name a vulnerability ?
If it is one, I would like to know why, and how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends where you store the filename. If you store the name in a database, in strictly typed variable, then HTML encode before you display it on a web page, there won't be any issues.

Comment: Yes, the filename is stored in a database, but this is a PHP website we're talking about, so strongly typed variable don't exist...I'm sorry I forgot to mention PHP because I thought that the problem wasn't language dependent but obviously I was wrong about that :)

Comment: @teum For SQL safety see this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php, for XSS prevention check this SO post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336776/xss-filtering-function-in-php) to start with

Comment: I'm already using PDO and filtering my input, so I guess everything is fine ?

Comment: @teum Then I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 6):

While this is an old question, it's surprisingly high on the list of search results when looking for 'security file names', so I'd like to expand on the existing answers:

**Yes, it's almost surely a vulnerability.**

There are several possible problems you might encounter if you try to *store a file using its original filename*:

- the filename could be a reserved or special file name. What happens if a user uploads a file called `.htaccess` that tells the webserver to parse all `.gif` files as PHP, then uploads a `.gif` file with a GIF comment of `<?php /* ... */ ?>`?
- the filename could contain `../`. What happens if a user uploads a file with the 'name' `../../../../../etc/cron.d/foo`? (This particular example should be caught by system permissions, but do *you* know all locations that your system reads configuration files from?)

  - if the user the web server runs as (let's call it `www-data`) is misconfigured and has a shell, how about `../../../../../home/www-data/.ssh/authorized_keys`? (Again, this particular example *should* be guarded against by SSH itself (and possibly the folder not existing), since the `authorized_keys` file needs very particular file permissions; but if your system is set up to give restrictive file permissions by default (tricky!), then that won't be the problem.)
- the filename could contain the `x00` byte, or control characters. System programs may not respond to these as expected - e.g. a simple `ls -al | cat` (not that I know why you'd want to execute that, but a more complex script might contain a sequence that ultimately boils down to this) might execute commands.
- the filename could end in `.php` and be executed once someone tries to download the file. (Don't [try blacklisting extensions](https://www.owasp.org/index.php?title=Unrestricted_File_Upload&oldid=242061#Blacklisting_File_Extensions).)

The way to handle this is to roll the filenames yourself (e.g. `md5()` on the file contents or the original filename). If you absolutely must allow the original filename to best of your ability, **whitelist** the file extension, **mime-type** check the file, and **whitelist** what *characters* can be used in the filename.

Alternatively, you can roll the filename yourself when you *store* the file and for use in the URL that people use to download the file (although if this is a file-serving script, you should avoid letting people specify filenames here, anyway, so no one downloads your `../../../../../etc/passwd` or other files of interest), but keep the original filename stored in the database for display somewhere. In this case, you only have SQL injection and XSS to worry about, which is ground that the other answers have already covered.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the files could reveal potentially sensitive information. Some companies/people use different naming conventions for documents, so you might end up with :

- Author name ( court-order-john.smith.doc )
- Company name ( sensitive-information-enterprisename.doc )
- File creation date ( letter.2012-03-29.pdf )

I think you get the point, you can probably think of some other information people use in their filenames.

Depending on what your site is about this could become an issue (consider if wikileaks published leaked documents that had the original source somewhere inside the filename).

If you decide to hide the filename, you must consider the problem of somebody submitting an executable as a document, and how you make sure people know what they are downloading.

Comment: Hmm, very good point, I skipped over the "publicly available" part.

Comment: I'm not worried at all about the name of the document containing sensitive information, and in my case, that's the user's problem. I'm just concerned about people naming their files in a way they can exploit some vulnerabilities. Moreover, I would like to be able to keep the original name because when someone downloads the file, if it's named like "resume_3242354543" he will not be able to know what file it is, this is secure but not user friendly. I'm looking for a compromise here between security and usability.

Comment: @teum In that case if you store the name in a strongly typed variable and encode before displaying, you'll be fine

Comment: At first I thought it wasn't worth mentionning it but it's in a PHP environment. So I can definitely forget about "strongly typed variables".