# Storing and displaying code using mysql_real_escape_string();

Tags: php, html, sql, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm creating a web page that will allow users to paste in their code and be given a unique URL to access it later. The problem is that I am using

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['code'])
```

to prevent sql injection but at the same it adds slashes to the code which means when the code is displayed at a later date, it is spoiled (slashes everywhere.)

Is there a way to 'un-escape' it when displaying the code again?

Sorry if this seems unclear or obvious, this is my first project using php.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions as they are [now deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Are you sure the slashes are from `mysql_real_escape_string()` or are they in `$_POST`?

Comment: The only thing `stripslashes()` is an answer to is "how do I fix my goofed up data?". PHP should be configured properly in the first place to *not cause this*.

Comment: @Jason: They're in both. Whee!

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, you doing okay man? :)

Comment: @Jason: No one is okay when PHP is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is echo stripslashes($code); you looking for? I think for added security you also have to like convert the special characters to html entities and strip all script tags if necessary to avoid xss attack.

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

[XSS filtering function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336776/xss-filtering-function-in-php)