# Why in the following php code trim,htmlspecialchars and stripslashes not working?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form which contains two fields Username and Password. I want to store the values entered by the user in an array named as stack.

The following code stores the values in the stack array and displays me the array with the exact values which i entered. Even if i have a slash or any html,javascript in my fields it just stores it into the array.

May i know where is my mistake as function check() is not executing properly.

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "test";
$stack = array();
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$db);
if(!$connect){
    die("Couldn't connect to the database");
    exit();
}
function check($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    foreach($_POST as $value){
        if($value == $_POST['login']){
        break;
        }
        else{
            check($value);
            array_push($GLOBALS['stack'],$value);
        }
    }
    print_r($stack);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the commented line.

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "test";
$stack = array();
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$db);
if(!$connect){
    die("Couldn't connect to the database");
    exit();
}
function check($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    foreach($_POST as $value){
        if($value == $_POST['login']){
        break;
        }
        else{
            $value = check($value); //returned value is not captured
            array_push($GLOBALS['stack'],$value);
        }
    }
    print_r($stack);
}

?>
```

Comment: may i know what to do so that the returned value is captured with the $value

Comment: i have change the line already. Please compare the line that i have added the comment.

Comment: It's not working. It again shows me the values with slash and all

Comment: try echo $value before pushing into array.

Comment: it echoes me the user input whatever i wrote in the fields including all the whitespaces and slashes

Comment: can you tell me any other method to get rid of the XSS and whitespaces, slashes

Comment: check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336776/xss-filtering-function-in-php

Answer (score 1):

you got two options.

- save the return value from the check function in a variable

  $value = check($value);
- change function check($data) to function check(&$data)