# Push CSS (Path) over a Parameter in URL

Tags: php, css, security

i want to offer customers a possibility to insert CSS into an Iframe for changing Colors and so on.

Is my Code a good way to do so? I already wrapped "GET" with htmlspecialchars in order to prevent an inject or closing tags, i.e. ?> in URL for running random new Code.

```html
<?
$css_url = null;
if ( isset($_GET["css_url"]) ) {
 $css_url = "". htmlspecialchars($_GET["css_url"]);
}
if ($css-url != null && strlen($css_url) > 0) {
 echo('<link href="'.$css_url.'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />');
}
?>
```

**Is it unsafe to run this?** Any suggestions and explanations why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XSS filtering function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336776/xss-filtering-function-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to be clear, you're not injecting CSS rules here, but a link to an external CSS file that must be hosted somewhere. **Is this really what you want?**

- Regarding the risk of XSS injection, you're fine with [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), as long as you provide the correct encoding of your page as 3rd parameter;
- You should, however, at the very least make a sanity check of the URL (check that it starts with `http://` or `https://`, and that it's syntactically valid;
- If your site is on `https`, you must only accept URLs starting with `https`, or you'll get an unsecure content warning in your browser;

Other than that, the risks should be very limited. If the link does not point to a valid CSS file, it will likely be ignored. The only real annoyance is the ability for an attacker to make visitors of your site trigger a `GET` request on any URL they want.

---

That being said, I would advise that you allow users to provide CSS *rules* instead, i.e. what goes inside a `<style>` tag. Now if you do this, it's a different story: you have to be sure that the provided CSS code does not contain `</style>`, or this opens the door to XSS injections.

If you're following this route, I would advise you to parse the CSS rules provided with a CSS parser such as [this one](https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser). This way, you can ensure that only valid CSS can be given, which is good for both security and quality.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Yes its about parsing a CSS FILE (FULL URL) over Parameter. Not just some Arguments.

Answer (score 0):

@Benjamin i edited Code with a friend. 
Any thoughts on this? We tried to insert your Suggestions:

```
$cssurl = null;
if ( isset($_GET["cssurl"]) ) {
    $cssurl = "". htmlspecialchars($_GET["cssurl"], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
}
if ($cssurl != null && strlen($cssurl) > 0) {
    if (strpos($cssurl, "https://") === 0) {
        if (strrpos($cssurl, ".css") === strlen($cssurl)-4) {
            echo('<link href="'.$cssurl.'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />');
        }
    }
}
```